# Remove last 5 characters in string - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, truncation

I am trying to clean up my Date/TimeStamp before I show it to the user on the page.

I am  pulling the following information from a database MSSQL and it is stored in the myDate variable:

```
#myDate#  =   2015-06-10 11:47:00.0
```

What I would like to do is cleanup `myDate` so that is looks like this:

```
2015-06-10 11:47
```

I have explored using `Left` but I believe that only works for strings.

I am not 100% sure how this is accomplished in ColdFusion.

Thanks let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Hint: Look in [the documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat) under date functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using CF9 or below, you can use `dateFormat()` and `timeFormat()` functions to accomplish it. Like this.

```
<cfoutput>
     #DateFormat(mydate, "yyyy-mm-dd")# #TimeFormat(mydate, "hh:mm")#
</cfoutput>
```

In case you want to display time in 24 hour format you can use `HH` as mask in `timeFormat()` function. For more details go through these links:

- [`DateFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff4.html)
- [`TimeFormat()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6de0.html)

If you are using CF10 or above then, as @Leigh suggested, you can use `dateTimeFormat()` function. Like this.

```
<cfoutput>
    #DateTimeFormat(mydate, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn")#
</cfoutput>
```

Where `nn` is the mask for displaying minutes. For more options go through the link @Leigh suggested.